# sys.stdin.read() in subprocess never returning

Tags: python, python-3.x, io

I'm trying to understand subprocess.Popen and subprocess.PIPE. While doing so, I created three small scripts.

The goal of this exercise is, to print data with one script, read it from the other and echo this back to the first script.

The problem is, that the last sys.stdin.read() prevents the entire code from working properly.

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

proc1 = Popen(["python3","script1.py"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
proc2 = Popen(["python3","script2.py"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)

first_output = proc1.stdout.read()

print("[test.py:] " + str(first_output))

proc2.stdin.write(first_output)
proc2.stdin.flush()
proc2.stdin.close()

answer = proc2.stdout.read()

print("[test.py:] " + str(answer))

proc1.stdin.write(answer)
```

**script1.py**

```
import sys

sys.stdout.write("Hello world")
sys.stdout.flush()

answer = str(sys.stdin.read())
```

The last line in script1.py `answer = str(sys.stdin.read())` causes the entire program to get stuck. If I comment it out, everything works fine.

Why is that so and why am I not able to communicate any further? I didn't find an answer yet.

**script2.py**

```
import sys

input_read = str(sys.stdin.read())

sys.stdout.write("[script2.py:] " + input_read + " input read")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Would it be better to write something around the lines of "as intended" or what would you recommend me changing the title to?

Comment: Hmm. *sys.stdin.read() in subprocess never returning* would describe the behavior without implying that this happens because a system facility isn't operating per spec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do:

```
first_output = proc1.stdout.read()
```

this tries to read everything `proc1` has to say; that is, it reads until the file handle is closed. That doesn't happen, because `proc1` is itself waiting to read:

```
answer = str(sys.stdin.read())
```

Communicating between processes using pipes can be a bit tricky. I'd recommend reading through [the documentation for the subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess).

To solve your immediate problem, I know of two simple solutions. One would be to switch to communicating in lines. In `script1.py`, write a newline:

```
sys.stdout.write("Hello world\n")
sys.stdouf.flush()

answer = str(sys.stdin.readline())
```

And in script2.py add a newline and switch to `readline` as well:

```
input_read = str(sys.stdin.readline())

sys.stdout.write("[script2.py:] " + input_read + " input read\n")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

The other approach would be to switch to using [`read1`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=read1#io.BufferedIOBase.read1) instead of read. It takes an argument for the number of bytes to read, but doesn't wait to receive that much data before returning it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out what my fault was. I find it a little difficult to enable communication between two processes. I will try to work with readline(). I already read the documentation about subprocess. I will have a closer look into the read documentation.

Comment: It worked just as I intended. readline() was the way to go. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to be of help!